# make a dynamic filter in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, config

I have a pipe, that can be reused across components. Typically when searching.

The HTML looks like this, and you can see that I have an array with "plantNumber" and "shortDescription", but it could be an endless list of properties

```
*ngFor="let workOrder of workOrders | filterArrayPipe: ['plantNumber', 'shortDescription']: searchFilter"
```

The filter looks like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterArrayPipe'
})
export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, config: any, q: string) {
    if (config && q) {
      return value.filter(result => {
        return result[config[0]].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1 
          || result[config[1]].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1;
      });
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like it to look more like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterArrayPipe'
})
export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, config: any, q: string) {
    if (config && q) {
      return value.filter(result => {
        for (let i = 0; i < config.length; i ++) {
          const type = config[i];
          return result[type].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

So the question is, how would I add the "and"|| in the return statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the return in that `for` loop, it will only ever check the first `config` item.

Instead, you can do something like:

```
  return value.filter(result => {
    for (let i = 0; i < config.length; i ++) {
      const type = config[i];
      if (result[type].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
```

This way, it will try every value in the `config` array, and only return false if it doesn't find a match.

Alternately, with the `some` function, you can do something like:

```
  return value.filter(result => {
    return config.some((type) => result[type].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1)
  });
```

Comment: @Johansrk No probs - glad to help. *P.S. I know it's been mentioned before, but using a pipe for filter, especially one with nested for loops, that calls `.toLowerCase` on every iteration, is going to be a very slow solution. This function will be called on every change detection cycle*

Comment: What could be another solution instead of a pipe?

Comment: Copy that function inside your component, and call it yourself whenever you want to re-filter the data (i.e. when the filter string changes)